# ionic : $location.path works only if I use $scope.$apply()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am very new to ionic and trying to implement camera functionality. I have setup states as below in routes.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider
  .state('capture', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/capture.html',
    controller: 'captureCtrl'
  })

  .state('selectColor', {
    url: '/selectColor',
    templateUrl: 'templates/selectColor.html',
    controller: 'selectColorCtrl'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
})
```

In capture.html i have an image on click on which camera opens using below method

```
$scope.capturePhoto = function() {
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.onPhotoDataSuccess, $scope.onFail, {
      quality: 30,
      targetWidth: 600,
      targetHeight: 600,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.FILE_URI,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
  }

  $scope.onPhotoDataSuccess = function(imageURI) {
    console.log(imageURI);
    $location.path('/selectColor');
  }

  $scope.onFail = function(message) {
    //alert('Failed because: ' + message);
  }
```

On photo success, control is coming to $scope.onPhotoDataSuccess method where I am trying to move to /selectColor using $location.path('selectColor') but it is not rendering the selectColor.html page normally and I have to use $scope.$apply() to make it appear.

I have experience of angular and AFAIK if you are already inside angular then you dont need to call $scope.$apply()

What is going wrong in my case and is there a different way to route to another page in ionic instead of $location.path()??

Thanks,
Prateek

Comment: Why are you not using `$state.go` though?

Comment: I am more familiar with angular. Angular-ui is also new to me. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on where $scope.onPhotoDataSuccess is being called from, when you consider whether or not you're "inside angular". Given that it's likely being called from navigator.camera, which isn't going to be somewhere in the angular functionality (ng-click, ng-submit, etc.), you'll have to continue to call `$scope.$apply()` to get it to function correctly. Nothing's wrong, that's how it's supposed to work.